# image gallery swipe in android studio

Tags: android, browser, image-gallery

completely new to android programming and trying to learn but running into a roadblock. I am using android studio.

I am trying to make a simple app for my child that has some of our pictures in it. There are about 30 pictures. All I want is a screen (activity?) that displays all 30 pictures, one at a time fullscreen. And just swipe to the left to go to the next picture.

Is this complicated to do? I've noticed so far in my experimenting everything that should be easy seems really complicated, like to go to another screen on button click requires massive lines of code in 3 different places. You would think there could just be a built-in template for simple things like that rather than having to type it all out each time. but I digress.

Would it be easier or harder to just have a web browser built in to the screen, showing images that I host online, instead of importing into the app and displaying them in the app? I only ask because I am good at html programming and basic, but completely new to java and xml.

Comment: where do the pictures come from?

Comment: Since you do html you could just have the app send an intent to the browser to open up a web page though there's little point to that over just using a bookmark in a browser unless there's more to the app.

There's a few ways to implement a gallery with swipe. Just google it.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of Android:

You can easily achieve a gallery using a View Pager where each page is an image.

View Pager has the swiping capabilities as well

Here's a detailed tutorial on using view pagers: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html